# Sending structure by socket and receiving chinese letters

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I have this structure in C++.

```
struct test
{
     int num;
     int quest;
     wchar_t name[64];
};

int main()
{
    test mystruct;
    mystruct.num = 12;
    mystruct.quest = 2;
    memcpy(mystruct.name,var1,sizeof(var1)); // var1 is an char [64] with the request name
    send(Socket->ConnectSocket, (char*)&mystruct, sizeof(test), 0);
}
```

On the other side i have the following code, written in C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private struct test
{
    public int num;
    public int quest;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string name;
}
........
test structtest;
this.Receiver_og.Receive(this.buffer);
this.structtest = (test)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(test));
```

This code works perfect except for the string name that I only see chinese letters. How can I fix it?

Comment: If I use char[64] to send it via socket, the data is not receiving well.

Comment: `string name[64];` is not a valid c# declaration.

Comment: I wrote it wrong, now the declaration is well.

Comment: It sounds like you may have been hacked by the Chinese. Are you working on the Microsoft cloud by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying a char array (which contains 8-bit characters) into a wchar_t array, which is expected to contain 16-bit unicode characters. Simply copying the chars gives you a 16-bit character that is a combination of two 8-bit chars, hence the junk. You need to convert the 8-bit chars into unicode characters using the MultiByteToWideChar API.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all your code, It seems like you are not setting up your connection.

As far as I know, though I haven't worked with sockets in c++ and c#, you need to set up the client/server by creating the socket, setting the options, binding, listening and then communicating.

You should look into [Beej's guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html), they have pretty much anything you need to setup a client/server program, specially the [Fifth Chapter](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html) where they walk you through the process of setting up the connection.

Comment: This isn't all my code. I tried to simplify , to make it easy. I receive well all the data except the name. I think It isn't a socket problem.